# How can I port bind an interactive transient PBS session to the head node and then port bind the head node to my local machine?

Tags: hpc, pbs

The short of it: How can I port bind an interactive transient PBS session to the head node and then port bind the head node to my local machine? So, a chain of port bind of three machines.

More details:

Disclaimer: I am not totally sure if I understand the minutiae of the differences between port binding and forwarding so if something I say sounds off assume fault on my part.

I have 3 machines with the following variables involved:

| Machine | Proxitimity | Super user access | Type | persistant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Laptop | Local | Yes | Opensuse | Yes |
| Head node | Remote | No | PBS headnode | Yes |
| Interactive node | Remote | No | PBS interactive session | NO |

I can do `ssh username@<ip-address> -L 8080:localhost:8080` ssh in the head-nodeand then do `jupyter lab --no-browser --port 8080` to open a connection to the remote `Jupyter` server on my laptop's GUI. **But the head node has a limited amount of power**.
But, we have access to interactive session that have a significantly higher upper limit on their compute capacity. I initiate and access them using the following PBS script

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N interactive-job
#PBS -V -j oe -o interactive-job.qlog
#PBS -P labpool
#PBS -l system_metrics=true
#PBS -l nodes=1,instance_type=m5.4xlarge,spot_price=auto,instance_ami=ami-0961c39af220b9f68
```

But when I do `jupyter lab --no-browser --port 8080` from inside the head-node, I can no longer access the remote `jupyter` server on my local GUI. I suspect this is because my local machine is port bound to the head node but not the interactive session.

Off the top of my head, I am thinking the solution would be to create a chain of port binding that connects the interactive session to the head node and the head node to my local machine. **How can I do this?**

I think I need to customize the script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N interactive-job
#PBS -V -j oe -o interactive-job.qlog
#PBS -P labpool
#PBS -l system_metrics=true
#PBS -l nodes=1,instance_type=m5.4xlarge,spot_price=auto,instance_ami=ami-0961c39af220b9f68

ssh interactive_session_name@new_ip -L 8080:localhost:8080 # **Not sure if this is right.**
```

The main technical issue is that `interactive_session_name@new_ip` change every time and show up after the `qsub -I job_script.sh`. **Is there a way to infer the names beforehand inside the script?**

Trying to look up customization for PBS on search engines has proven difficult because I more often than not run into articles about the other PBS(public broadcasting service).

Any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate [An SSH tunnel via multiple hops](https://superuser.com/questions/96489/an-ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops)

Comment: Not really, because `PBS` variables are part of the issue. I need PBS params to do the forwarding.

Comment: Well, you should check your installed queuing system. A short look into PBS reveals, that there are environment variables such as $PBS_NODEFILE, (e.g. [see section 2.3](https://uni-tuebingen.de/fileadmin/Uni_Tuebingen/Einrichtungen/ZDV/Bilder/Computing/batch_doc-1.pdf)), which can be used to identify the host. Wether this is available on your system is up to you to check.